# Ruby C extensions API questions

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

So, recently I had the unfortunate need to make a C extension for Ruby (because of performance). Since I was having problems with understanding `VALUE` (and still do), so I looked into the Ruby source and found: `typedef unsigned long VALUE;` ([Link to Source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/2b44bbf6970fbc9f5bf82f7316a8b2a5a8b460d4/include/ruby/ruby.h#L88), but you will notice that there are a few other 'ways' it's done, but I think it's essentially a `long`; correct me if I'm wrong). So, while investigating this further I found an interesting [blog post](http://www.rubyfleebie.com/ruby-and-c-part-1/), which says:

> "...in some cases the VALUE object could BE the data instead of POINTING TO the data."

What confuses me is that, when I attempt to pass a string to C from Ruby, and use `RSTRING_PTR();` on the `VALUE` (passed to the C-function from Ruby), and try to 'debug' it with `strlen();` it returns 4. *Always* 4.

example code:

```
VALUE test(VALUE inp) {
    unsigned char* c = RSTRING_PTR(inp);
    //return rb_str_new2(c); //this returns some random gibberish
    return INT2FIX(strlen(c));
}
```

This example returns always 1 as the string length:

```
VALUE test(VALUE inp) {
    unsigned char* c = (unsigned char*) inp;
    //return rb_str_new2(c); // Always "\x03" in Ruby.
    return INT2FIX(strlen(c));
}
```

Sometimes in ruby I see an Exception saying "Can't convert Module to String" (or something along those lines, <del>however I was messing with the code so much trying to figure this out that I am unable to reproduce the error now</del> the error would happen when I tried `StringValuePtr();` [I'm a bit unclear what this exactly does. Documentation says it changes the passed paramater to `char*`] on inp):

```
VALUE test(VALUE inp) {
    StringValuePtr(inp);
    return rb_str_new2((char*)inp); //Without the cast, I would get compiler warnings
}
```

So, the Ruby code in question is: `MyMod::test("blahblablah")`

**EDIT**: Fixed a few typos and updated the post a little.

---

### The questions

1. What exactly does `VALUE imp` hold? A pointer to the object/value?
   The value itself?
2. If it holds the value itself: when does it do that, and is there a way to check for it?
3. How do I actually access the value (since I seem to accessing almost everything *but*
   the value)?

P.S: My understanding of C isn't really the best, but it's a work in progress; also, read the comments in the code snippets for some additional description (if it helps).

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Ruby Strings vs. C strings**

Let's start with strings first. First of all, before trying to retrieve a string in C, it is good habit to call `StringValue(obj)` on your `VALUE` first. This ensures that you will really deal with a Ruby string in the end because if it is not already a string, then it will turn it into one by coercing it with a call to that object's `to_str` method. So this makes things safer and prevents the occasional segfault you might get otherwise.

The next thing to watch out for is that Ruby strings are not `\0`-terminated as your C code would expect them to make things like `strlen` etc. work as expected. Ruby's strings carry their length information with them instead - that's why in addition to `RSTRING_PTR(str)` there is also the `RSTRING_LEN(str)` macro to determine the actual length.

So what `StringValuePtr` now does is returning the non-zero-terminated `char *` to you - this is great for buffers where you have a separate length, but not what you want for e.g. `strlen`. Use `StringValueCStr` instead, it will modify the string to be zero-terminated so that it is safe for usage with functions in C that expect it to be zero-terminated. But, try to avoid this wherever possible, because this modification is much less performant than retrieving the non-zero-terminated string that does not have to be modified at all. It's surprising if you keep an eye on this how rarely you will actually need "real" C strings.

**self as an implicit VALUE argument**

Another reason why your current code doesn't work as expected is that every C function to be called by Ruby gets passed `self` as an implicit `VALUE`.

- No arguments in Ruby ( e.g. obj.doit ) translates to

  > VALUE doit(VALUE self)
- Fixed amount of arguments (>0, e.g. obj.doit(a, b)) translates to

  > VALUE doit(VALUE self, VALUE a, VALUE b)
- Var args in Ruby ( e.g. obj.doit(a, b=nil)) translates to

  > VALUE doit(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self)

in Ruby. So what you were working on in your example is *not* the string passed to you by Ruby but actually the current value of `self`, that is the object that was the receiver when you called that function. A correct definition for your example would be

```
static VALUE test(VALUE self, VALUE input)
```

I made it `static` to point out another rule that you should follow in your C extensions. Make your C functions only public if you intend to share them among several source files. Since that's almost never the case for function that you attach to a Ruby class, you should declare them as `static` by default and only make them public if there is a good reason to do so.

**What is VALUE and where does it come from?**

Now to the harder part. If you dig down deeply into Ruby internals, then you will find the function [rb_objnew](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/gc.c#L1151) in gc.c. Here you can see that any newly created Ruby object becomes a `VALUE`by being cast as one from something called the `freelist`. It's defined as:

```
#define freelist objspace->heap.freelist
```

You can imagine the `objspace` as a huge map that stores each and every object that is currently alive at a given point in time in your code. This is also where the garbage collector fulfills his duty and the `heap` struct in particular is the place where new objects are born. The "freelist" of the heap is again declared as being an `RVALUE *`. This is the C-internal representation of the Ruby built-in types. An `RVALUE` is actually defined as follows:

```
typedef struct RVALUE {
    union {
    struct {
        VALUE flags;        /* always 0 for freed obj */
        struct RVALUE *next;
    } free;
    struct RBasic  basic;
    struct RObject object;
    struct RClass  klass;
    struct RFloat  flonum;
    struct RString string;
    struct RArray  array;
    struct RRegexp regexp;
    struct RHash   hash;
    struct RData   data;
    struct RTypedData   typeddata;
    struct RStruct rstruct;
    struct RBignum bignum;
    struct RFile   file;
    struct RNode   node;
    struct RMatch  match;
    struct RRational rational;
    struct RComplex complex;
    } as;
    #ifdef GC_DEBUG
    const char *file;
    int   line;
    #endif
} RVALUE;
```

That is, basically a union of core data types that Ruby knows about. Missing something? Yes, Fixnums, Symbols, `nil` and boolean values are not included there. It's because these kinds of objects are directly represented using the `unsigned long` that a `VALUE` boils down to in the end. I think the design decision there was (besides being a cool idea) that dereferencing a pointer might be slightly less performant than the bit shifts that are currently needed when transforming the `VALUE` to what it actually represents. Essentially

```
obj = (VALUE)freelist;
```

says give me whatever freelist points to currently and treat is as `unsigned long`. This is safe because freelist is a pointer to an `RVALUE` - and a pointer can also be safely interpreted as `unsigned long`. This implies that every `VALUE` except those carrying Fixnums, symbols, nil or Booleans are essentially pointers to an `RVALUE`, the others are directly represented within the `VALUE`.

Your last question, how can you check for what a `VALUE` stands for? You can use the `TYPE(x)` macro to check whether a `VALUE`'s type would be one of the "primitive" ones.

Comment: I just got back to this question accidentally after a while, and damn, this answer got sexier.

Comment: what if you do have binary data in your Ruby "String" , which can contain zero-bytes? What macro or function should I use to convert the `VALUE input` into a `unsigned char *` ?

Comment: @Tilo You can `RSTRING_PTR(VALUE ruby_string)` or `StringValuePtr(VALUE ruby_string)`on it. It will give you the `unsigned char*` you're looking for. However, it won't be null-terminated, so you won't be able to use Cs built-in string functions, but if it contains binary data, you probably don't need to use them anyway! :D

Comment: Thanks, your insight for `StringValueCStr` being _heavy_ was definitely helpful, I was trying to make a heavily performant extension and required such optimizations

Answer (score 5):

```
VALUE test(VALUE inp)
```

The first issue is here: inp is self (so, in your case, the module). If you want to refer to the first argument, you need to add a self argument before that (which makes me to add `-Wno-unused-parameters` to my cflags, as it is never used in the case of module functions):

```
VALUE test(VALUE self, VALUE inp)
```

Your first example uses a module as a string, which certainly won't result into anything good. `RSTRING_PTR` lacks type checks, which is a good reason not to use it.

A VALUE is a reference to the Ruby object, but not directly a pointer to what it may contain (like a char* in the case of a string). You need to get that pointer using some macros or functions depending on each object. For a string, you want `StringValuePtr` (or `StringValueCStr` to ensure that the string is null-terminated) which *returns* the pointer (it doesn't *change* the content of your VALUE in any way).

```
strlen(StringValuePtr(thing));
RSTRING_LEN(thing); /* I assume strlen was just an example ;) */
```

The actual content of the `VALUE` is, in MRI and YARV at least, the `object_id` of the object (or at least, it is after a bitshift).

For your own objects, the VALUE will most likely contain a pointer to a C object which you can get using `Data_Get_Struct`:

```
 my_type *thing = NULL;
 Data_Get_Struct(rb_thing, my_type, thing);
```

Comment: +1, just one remark: it should be VALUE test(VALUE self, VALUE inp), no? self always at the beginning for fixed-args functions?

Comment: Ah +1 for both of the splendid questions. I don't know which one to accept. I am slightly leaning towards @emboss's answer, since it's more detailed and explanatory, but both were splendid and helpful... Unicorns among answers I'd say. :D